# Ng Date Picker How to format to different output instead of ISO-8601

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

First, for people wondering, I'm referring to this DatePicker

https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/#locale-formats

While the DatePicker feels and looks great, I have an issue with the outputting values. There are numerous options to format the view-part of a date, but I haven't seen or found examples or explanations on how I can switch the outputted ISO-8601 (2018-08-29T00:00:00.000Z) standard in my form. I'm using the datepicker in a reactive form and I have several pages with a similar prerequisite. I need to parse this value into a different format. For example...

```
29-08-2018
```

My first attempt - which wasn't too smart to begin with - was using [(ngModel)]="dateField" to grab the value that is inputted and change it into a value that I wanted to. Needless to say, of course it was changed in the view as well and since I didn't refer to index of the form field it merely caused a blank field. Shortly after I realized that the approach was poor to begin with, but since I can't find configurations for this particular problem I'm pretty lost as to what I can do.

[image: https://imgur.com/dZYQObD]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ak.leimrey. Normally all the datepicker give you a value of one type (in your case a string format in ISO, other case, e.g. using ng-bootstrap, return an object with day,month and year). if you want to send in other format, in the submit you can map the values and convert the form.value.

```
submit(form)
{
   if (form.valid)
   {
      let result={
         ...form.value, //all the values of the form, but change some one
         searchParams:form.value.searchParams.map(x=>{
             ...x
             value.map(v=>{
                let items=v.split('-');
                return items[2].substr(0,2)+"-"+items[1]+"-"+items[0];
             })
         })
      }
      console.log(result)
   }
}
```

Yes in your case transform the object is some hard but see as using the spread operator and map you can transform the value

Comment: Seems like this is the only sensible solution left! Wish out backend guy would work with actual standardized date formats instead. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

use moment js libaray . its a simple and rich library that can help u ;

u can get it via npm : npm i moment .

then u can convert formats like this :

```
moment("2018-08-29","YYYY-MM-DD").format("YYYY-DD-MM"); // outputs : 2018-29-08
```

or

```
moment("2018-08-29","YYYY-MM-DD").format("DD-MM-YYYY"); // outputs : 29-08-2018
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't solve the underlying issue. I'm aware you can format dates with moment, but how do I do that in the context of the datepicker?